# How to stop xBim IfcStore.Open() operation?

Tags: c#, xbim

I have a simple question - is it possible to stop/cancel xBim

```
   var model = IfcStore.Open(...)
```

method once it has started to create database?
I have wrapped it in Task.Run like this to keep my app responsive, but of course cancellationTokenSource does not help much:

```
   var readDataBase = Task.Run(() =>
   {
      model = IfcStore.Open(fileName, editor);
   }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Comment: Thank you for the question. This is not possible at the moment, but I added it as a [work item in the project](https://github.com/orgs/xBimTeam/projects/2/views/1?pane=issue&itemId=12468592). I'd like to support cancellable async operations in the next major release.

Comment: @Martin Cerny Thank you for shedding some light on this! Looking forward to seeing this in future!